How to create a raster server with PostGIS and MapLibre
I'm trying to create an interface for a raster layer stored in PostGIS. My idea is to create a tile server that will take a query such as SELECT * FROM my_raster and selectively query against that result based on the x/y/z zoom position of the client. I don't want to bake out a tile pyramid ahead of time because I want these queries to be dynamic.
This works well for data stored a vector but I'm running into an issue with properly displaying raster tiles. You can see a demo server here but I will explain the relevant code.
My current approach is to upload the raster file as separate tiles. (The alternative is upload the entire raster as one row but that led to slow query times when I tried it).
Here is the SQL query template that I am using to extract a tile and serve it as a png where $query is something like SELECT * FROM my_raster.
WITH tilebounds (geom) AS (SELECT ST_TileEnvelope($1, $2, $3)),
query AS (
  $query
)
SELECT
  st_aspng(
    st_resize(
      st_union(
        st_clip(
          query.rast,
          tilebounds.geom
        )
      ), 512, 512
    )
  )
FROM
  query, tilebounds
where st_intersects(query.rast, tilebounds.geom)

On the front-end, the MapLibre client is initialized like this:
map.addSource('my-raster', {
    type: 'raster',
    tiles: ['http://localhost:4000/raster/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'],
    tileSize: 512
});
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'raster-data',
    'type': 'raster',
    'source': 'my-raster',
    'paint': {
        'raster-opacity': 0.75
    },
});

With this setup, I'm running into two issues:

When I zoom in, the tiles served from the server are not flush against one another


When I zoom out, some of the tiles around the edges get stretched in weird ways.



I think the issue has to do with a mismatch between the tileSize PostGIS is rendering vs what MapLibre is asking for but since I set them both to 512, I'm not sure what else to change. Since the stretching occurs at the edges, there may also be some tweak needed to the query to handle parts of the map where the query is empty. Those are just my best guesses, though.

Out of curiosity, does it work with leaflet?

Oddly, the raster shows up south of Africa, so something is off with the projection in a way that is very confusing since the same server is backing both. The leaflet version only shows the raster when the map is zoomed out, though. When I zoom in the layer disappears. I updated the original post with better images showing the maplibre tile boundaries.
